# Cannot build Embeddinator-4000 in VisualStudio missing Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embeddinator

I am trying to build `Embeddinator-4000` with VisualStudio

```
Building
Clone this repository
Initialize/update submodules: git submodule update --recursive --init
Open the solution file Embeddinator-4000.sln with Visual Studio or Visual Studio For Mac
Build
```

however I am stuck with these error build errors

```
AndroidSdkBase.cs(258,60,258,71): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotNullWhenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
AndroidSdkBase.cs(258,60,258,71): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotNullWhen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
AndroidSdkBase.cs(276,65,276,76): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotNullWhenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
AndroidSdkBase.cs(276,65,276,76): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotNullWhen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
AndroidSdkBase.cs(294,60,294,71): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotNullWhenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
AndroidSdkBase.cs(294,60,294,71): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotNullWhen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

AndroidSdkUnix.cs(11,29,11,39): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AndroidSdk' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Android.Tools' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
AndroidSdkWindows.cs(7,29,7,39): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AndroidSdk' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Android.Tools' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

i am new to VisualStudio and have no idea how to fix these errors.

what seems odd is i can build the Xamarin.Android.Tools project fine with no errors at all

How can i resolve theses build issues?